# Create a universal vector image programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, vector, uiimage, universal

We can now create universal vector images in Xcode by adding them into image assets folder and then changing the scale factors to single vector. I would like to know how to do this programmatically. I've tried the following but no luck :(

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newSize: CGSize) -> (UIImage) {
    let newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0,0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
    let imageRef = image.CGImage

    let scaleFactor = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, scaleFactor)

  //  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.5)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Set the quality level to use when rescaling

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, CGInterpolationQuality.High)


    let flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height)

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical)
    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef)

    let newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)! as CGImage
    let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: newImageRef)

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage

}
```

Comment: I allow the user to select an image from their photo album which I then display in a pdf. I've tested using images that I manually put into the image asset folder and then I set the scale factor to single vector via the story board but I want to programmatically take the user's image and set it's scale factor to single vector.

Comment: be aware that using the screen scale most of the times your images width and height will come twice as expected. Most devices uses 2.0 scale. You should use 1.0 value if you would like your final image to be the same size as your newSize parameter. You will also distort the images if you don't keep the same aspect ratio from the original image

Comment: I have to use 0.5 to get my final image the size I want. My problem is my users will have devices with different scale factors. If it was as easy as dividing each scale by 4. I don't have 1.0 or 3.0 devices to check.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.  Yea...Apple kind of gears this towards setting it in storyboard by ticking the preserve vector data.  I'm not sure how to preserve vector data programmatically.

```
    public class var add: UIImage {
    let path = bundle.url(forResource: "plusReal", withExtension: "pdf")
    return drawPDFFromURL(url: path!)!
}

class func drawPDFFromURL(url: URL) -> UIImage? {
      guard let document = CGPDFDocument(url as CFURL),
            let page = document.page(at: 1) else {return nil }
    let pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)

    let img = renderer.image { ctx in
        UIColor.white.set()
        ctx.fill(pageRect)
        ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageRect.size.height)
        ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page)
    }
    return img
}
```